# R programming graphics command

Tags: r

What is the R command to write the caption of the figure using R language so that the caption of the figure can be given below the plot.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Check out Sweave or RMarkdown, captions are for documents usually. If you really want the caption on the plot see ?text, ?mtext and ?par.

Answer (score 2):

## in Rmarkdown:

````
```{r my_fig_with_caption, fig.cap=fn('My Figure')}
plot(rnorm(100)
```
````

see: http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/using_markdown.